# What are badges, and how do they work?

Tags: tetris-99

There is an attacking option called "Badges".

[image]

What are badges, and how do they work?  What does the 000% UP stand for at the very bottom?  From what I've looked up they serve as "gear" for players, similar to games like Fortnite and Apex:Legends, but I still don't understand how significant they are, and how badges are acquired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Badges are essentially powerups. You earn a badge piece for KO-ing other players and also get all the badge pieces the player you just KO'd had at that point. Once you collected enough badge pieces to complete a badge you get a bonus to garbage lines you are sending to other players while attacking. That bonus is indicated by the 000% UP. The amount of badge pieces needed to complete a badge and how it affects your bonus is as follows:

1st badge | 2 badge pieces | +25% lines

2nd badge | 4 badge pieces (6 total) | +50% lines

3rd badge | 8 badge pieces (14 total) | +75% lines

4th badge (maximum) | 16 badge pieces (30 total) | +100% lines

As an example: You just KO'd a player that had 5 badge pieces (1st badge completed and 3 additional pieces) already while you had none so far. That means you will get the 5 badge pieces they had collected up to that point and one additional piece for getting the KO, meaning you just completed your first 2 badges resulting in your attacks sending 50% more lines.